# How to translate an SQL query to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How to translate an SQL query to LINQ

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.Id
FROM Questions AS q
    JOIN TagsQuestions AS tq
        ON q.Id = tq.QuestionForeignKey
    JOIN Tags AS t
        ON t.Id = tq.TagForeignKey 
WHERE t.Name IN ('C#', '.Net')
GROUP BY q.Id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly,** You should note use `DISTINCT q.Id` because it's already `GROUP BY q.Id`.

```
SELECT q.Id
FROM Questions AS q
    JOIN TagsQuestions AS tq ON q.Id = tq.QuestionForeignKey
    JOIN Tags AS t ON t.Id = tq.TagForeignKey 
WHERE t.Name IN ('C#', '.Net')
GROUP BY q.Id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

**Secondly**, You can transfer from sql to linq syntax like below

```
var TagNames = new[] {
    "C#",
    ".Net"
};

var result = from q in Questions
      join tq in TagsQuestions on q.Id equals tq.QuestionForeignKey
      join t in Tags on t.Id equals tq.TagForeignKey
         where TagNames.Contains(t.Name)
      group q by q.Id into g
         where g.Count() = 2
      select g.Key;
```